# Finding $\frac{\partial g\left(x,x+y\right)}{\partial x}$?

Tags: partial-derivative

Suppose I have a function such that
\begin{align}
f\left(x,y\right)&=x^2+y^2+xy,
\end{align}
now let $v=x+y\implies y=v-x$, therefore
\begin{align}
f\left(x,v-x\right)&=x^2+\left(v-x\right)^2+x\left(v-x\right)\\
\require{cancel}&=x^2+v^2-\cancel{xv}+\cancel{x^2}+\cancel{xv}-\cancel{x^2}-2vx\\
&=x^2-2vx+v^2.
\end{align}
Now I'm going to let
\begin{align}
g\left(x,v\right)=x^2-2vx+v^2.
\end{align}

---

Suppose now that I want to find $\displaystyle\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$? It seems I would have to add in the piece from before since $v=y+x$, but how do I do that throughout the chain rule of partial differentials? This is what I think might happen:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}&=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x},\tag{1}
\end{align}
and if I might want to find $\displaystyle\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$ I would have to do something like
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}&=\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y},\tag{2}
\end{align}
but are $\left(1\right)$ and $\left(2\right)$ right?

Comment: Equation (1) is necessarily wrong as $\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Chain rule is not so helpful here, as it calculates derivative of composition of two or more functions, but you may write:

$$
\frac{\partial g(x,v(x,y))}{\partial x} = 2x - 2 v -2x \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + 2v \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}= 0.
$$

Note that:

$$
g(x,v) = (x-v)^2 = y^2 \Rightarrow  \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}= 2y .
$$

Comment: $v$ is not a function of one variable though. So it should be $\displaystyle\frac{\partial g\left(x,v\left(x,y\right)\right)}{\partial x}$...?

Comment: Yes you're right.

Comment: Also, note that this two equations are correct only if we know _a priori_ that $v=v(x,y)$ otherwise $\partial_{y}g=0$.